# How to generate a number uniformly from some joint intervals?

Tags: r

In R, I want to generate a number uniformly from the interval [-1.5, -0.5] U [0.5, 1.5]. Do we have such built-in function?

Comment: `x <- runif(100, -1, 1); x <- x + sign(x)/2` perhaps

Comment: So I think the answer is "not built in", but it's not hard with that distribution to rig something into a function like that

Comment: @r2evans, please post as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is nothing "built-in" for that, though it's not hard to contrive. Since your two ranges have the same range and are perfectly symmetric around zero, you can do:

```r
x <- runif(1000, -1, 1); x <- x + sign(x)/2
```

and while not perfect *proof* that it works, plotting it shows where the numbers are contained:

```r
plot(x)
```

[image: plot showing basic distribution areas for x]

This can be generalized a little:

```r
rfunc <- function(n, ranges) {
  stopifnot(
    length(ranges) > 0,
    all(lengths(ranges) == 2),
    all(sapply(ranges, function(r) r[2] > r[1])),
    !anyNA(unlist(ranges))
  )
  if (length(ranges) == 1) return(runif(n, min = ranges[[1]][1], max = ranges[[1]][2]))
  mtx <- do.call(rbind, ranges)
  diffs <- cumsum(c(0, mtx[,2] - mtx[,1]))
  diffs2 <- lapply(1:(length(diffs)-1), function(i) diffs[i+0:1])
  x <- runif(n, min = 0, max = max(diffs))
  out <- rep(NA, 0)
  for (i in seq_along(ranges)) {
    fm <- diffs2[[i]]
    to <- ranges[[i]]
    ind <- (x >= fm[1] & x <= fm[2])
    out[ind] <- to[1] + diff(to) * (x[ind] - fm[1]) / diff(fm)
  }
  out
}

# effectively the same as `runif`
x <- rfunc(1000, list(c(0, 1)))
# your range
x <- rfunc(1000, list(c(-1.5, -0.5), c(0.5, 1.5)))
# arbitrary number of ranges
x <- rfunc(1000, list(c(-1.5, -0.5), c(0.5, 1.5), c(2, 10)))
```

Walk-through:

- several safeguards in the `stopifnot`, confirming what needs to be true of `ranges` (I guess technically we could add some tests on `n` as well)
- a quick preemptive short-circuit: if `ranges` is length 1, then it is identical to calling `runif` on that range, so we do that instead; it adds but one line to the call and can be removed for reduction of code (and *technically* a little speed, though not much and likely not easily measurable)
- we convert a list of vectors into a matrix, mostly for convenience of some things ... I could easily have broken it into "firsts" and "seconds" or such for the same effect with very little change otherwise
- we need `diffs`, which is a cumulative sum of the range of each of the `ranges`; in your example, each of your two ranges has a difference of `1`, so `diffs <- c(0, cumsum(c(1, 1)))` or `c(0, 1, 2)`
- the internal `runif` calculates normal uniform from `0` to the max of this cumulative sum; we then `findInterval` (similar to `cut`) so that we have a proportional number of `x`s within each `ranges`-band
- we then iterate over each vector-pair of `diffs2` and `ranges`, find the `x`s that are within `diffs2[[i]]` and scale those numbers to be within `ranges[[i]]`

Since this function is effectively a conditional-scaling around `runif`, it uses the same amount of entropy but with a little computational cost to rescale the numbers according to the bins.

Answer (score 0):

A cheapo method:

```
x <- runif(100, 0.5,1.5)
y <- runif(100)
x[y<0.5] <- -x[y<0.5]
```